# Google pagespeed insights uses android AGENT for desktop

Tags: pagespeed, core-web-vitals

I often use google's pagespeed insights. But lately I'm facing problem with it's results.
For desktop view somehow it uses Android phone agent to test.

Made simple script to show agent and made test in tool for the url and here are results:

[image]

Any idea, how to prevent that? Or why i'm getting such 'tests' with wrong Agent?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that there's no caching or something on the page you're testing?  We cannot reproduce the android UA being used for the desktop test.

If you analyze https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+user+agent or https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent you'll see a desktop UA in the desktop tab.